# Validate a multiple upload backpack field as sometimes and required

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

I'm using [Backpack for Laravel](https://github.com/laravel-backpack) and i'm implementing `upload_multiple` [Field](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/4.1/crud-fields#upload_multiple)

I'm trying to validate this field as `sometimes`, only `required` if there aren't any items :

- if there's items selected to be uploaded, then proceed.
- if nothing selecting, and there're existing items, proceed also.
- But if there aren't any selected items and nothing existing before, then show the `required` field error message.

Debugging the post request, assuming the field name is `photos[]` it always having the first item as `null` :

```
[
    "photos" => [
        0 => null
    ]
]
```

So when i validate using `sometimes|required`

```
"photos" => "between:1,4",
"photos.*" => "sometimes|required|mimes:png,jpeg,jpg|max:2048"
```

if an item(s) selected, it's proceeding and uploading them.
now when i try to submit the form without selecting any items (by knowing there's existing items uploaded before), it's showing the `required field error message`.

because the `photos` Array always having the first item as `null` if nothing selected **as i mentioned above**.

A solution to deal with this, is to provide `nullable` to the validation rule :

```
"photos.*" => "sometimes|nullable|..."
```

But with `nullable` set to rules, the `required` rule will never work.

Maybe the main issue is because `photos[]` is always having the first item as `null` if nothing selected.

And it should always care about existing uploaded items in the validation, see if there's existing items uploaded then do not show required error messages, if not and the submit request has empty `photos` then show the required error.

How can i achieve this?

Comment: Just check if you have used this trait in your model. `HasUploadFields` 
path `Backpack\CRUD\app\Models\Traits;`

I had kind of the same issue and after using it, it was solved.

Comment: By default when i use the **CrudTrait** it includes **HasUploadFields**
i used the trait in my model anyway and i still have same problem.
see here: https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/CRUD/blob/master/src/app/Models/Traits/CrudTrait.php